# Starvation in Priority Thread Schedule by Setting Affinity to Single CPU

Tags: c, linux-kernel, scheduling, windows-subsystem-for-linux, affinity

I'm trying to create some code that will simulate starvation of multiple threads based on priority scheduling (FIFO). The code below is supposed to set the program affinity to a single CPU so that no multi-threading can occur, then I spawn all the threads with different priorities and wait a sec to make sure they are all set up and in a waiting state after which I release the mutex and due to the FIFO scheduling policy the thread with the highest priority should be able to proceed and then run forever starving the other 2 threads. Here is my code...

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sched.h>
#include <unistd.h>

//global variables
pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t cond = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;

void* tfun(void*n){
    struct sched_param param;
    int num_runs = 20;

    //set priority
    param.sched_priority = (int) n;
    sched_setscheduler(0, SCHED_FIFO, &param);

    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &mutex);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

    while(num_runs) {
            printf("thread priority: %d\n", (int) n);
            //num_runs = num_runs -1;
    }

    return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])       
{
    pthread_t tid1, tid2, tid3;
    cpu_set_t cpus;

    CPU_ZERO(&cpus);
    CPU_SET(0, &cpus);
    sched_setaffinity(0, sizeof(cpu_set_t), &cpus);

    pthread_create(&tid1, NULL, tfun, (void *) 40);
    pthread_create(&tid2, NULL, tfun, (void *) 30);
    pthread_create(&tid3, NULL, tfun, (void *) 20);

    sleep(1);
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    pthread_cond_broadcast(&cond);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

    pthread_join(tid1, NULL);
    pthread_join(tid2, NULL);
    pthread_join(tid3, NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

When I run it, instead of getting my expected behavior of "thread priority: 40" printed endlessly, it seems to cycle between all the different threads still and print them out as well.

I'm not sure if there is anything wrong with my code, but I am using the WSL (Windows subsystem for linux) and I was wondering if that was maybe causing my issue as the affinity setting is a linux thing that may not translate correctly in it?

build command
`$gcc -o main main.c -pthread -std=gnu99 -D_GNU_SOURCE`
run command (sudo because changing priorities)
`$sudo ./main`

Comment: The threads do next-to-nothing except make printf() I/O calls. The printf() I/O call has a mutex lock to protect the output stream from multiple access.  The lock has a queue for threads waiting for the mutex.   I suspect that the threads may be queueing up on the lock. Forward progress is not constrained or managed by CPU priority in this case.   Not posting this as an answer, though:)

Comment: @MartinJames just wanted to say that I've now confirmed it is the WSL. I installed Ubuntu and ran the program. running without sudo gives same behavior as on WSL, running with sudo and, as intended, the program starves and only the thread with priortiy 40 can print