# WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux) how to set CPU / core?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, scheduler, cpu-cores

I had [asked this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52962351/starvation-in-priority-thread-schedule-by-setting-affinity-to-single-cpu) several days ago and have finally gotten a definitive answer when I had some time earlier today to install Ubuntu on a VM. Basically, it would seem that the WSL does not behave correctly when attempting to set the CPU of a program. On the WSL when I ran my code both with and without sudo, the output was the same, all threads printing seemingly at random. However, on my Ubuntu VM, running the same code without sudo had the same effect, and running it with sudo caused the original goal of the code, and starved the other 2 threads allowing only the the process with the highest affinity (in this case 40) to print.

I was hoping someone here knew the WSL very intimately and could help me achieve the intended behavior on it.